# Does arrangement/order of tables in FROM clause make any difference in improving performance?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In general, does arrangement or order of tables in the FROM clause make any difference in improving the performance of the query? By arrangement I mean smallest table and largest table.

Any different experience/ideas/opinions/factors are also appreciated.

In my case, we're using PostgreSQL v8.2.3.

Comment: Offtopic: Version 8.2.3 is almost 4 years old and 16 releases behind. You have to do some maintenance. Updating to 8.2.19 is not a big deal, just do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *inner* joins, it should not make any difference- the optimiser will generate plans doing the joins in as many different orders as is possible (up to geqo_threshold tables in the *from* clause).

Outer joins are not symmetric, so there the ordering in the statement is significant (although the actual execution order is still decided by the server).

Comment: I agree. The PostgreSQL planner is smart enough to pick the correct "order" of the tables based on the statistics. For outer joins it does of course make a difference (but then it makes a difference in the result as well)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the existence of `geqo (Genetic Query Optimizer)` in query planning.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using something like "SELECT FROM table1,table2" ? 
The tables are "implicitly" cross-joined, so I don't think it matters.

The first thing I would do is test two possible queries using EXPLAIN, and see if there is any difference?

Answer (score 0):

(Generic SQL advice, rather than Postgre specific)

It *shouldn't* make a difference - the optimizer should be building a plan based on the information it has available to it, and SQL has generally been designed so that the optimizer is free to reorder joins, condition checks, etc, provided that the result is the same.

It may be that a particular query causes problems for a particular optimizer (for a certain DB, server state, version of product, etc), but it should be rare to encounter such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `FROM foo, bar, baz` then no, it doesn't make a difference.  If you write `FROM foo JOIN bar ... JOIN baz ...` (inner joins), then it doesn't make a difference if you have less than [`join_collapse_limit`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-JOIN-COLLAPSE-LIMIT) elements; otherwise the join order is fixed, which you can use to manually optimize such things (but that is rarely needed).  For outer joins, the join order is fixed as it is written, because that affects the results.